# Pandas Dataframe: Reduce the value of a 'Days' by 1 if the corresponding 'Year' is a leap year

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

If 'Days' is greater than e.g 10 and corresponding 'Year' is a leap year, then reduce 'Days' by 1 only in that particular row. I tried some operations but couldn't do it. I am new in pandas. Appreciate any help.

sample data:

```
data = [['1', '2005'], ['2', '2006'], ['3', '2008'],['50','2009'],['69','2008']] 
df=pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['Days','Year'])
```

I want 'Days' of row 5 to become 69 and everything else remains the same.

Comment: It's `69` not `59`

Comment: Sorry, the value should be 69 instead of 59.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [98]: import calendar
In [99]: data = [['1', '2005'], ['2', '2006'], ['3', '2008'],['50','2009'],['70','2008']] ;df=pd.DataFrame(data,column
    ...: s=['Days','Year'])

In [100]: df = df.astype(int)

In [102]: df["New_Days"] = df.apply(lambda x: x["Days"]-1 if (x["Days"] > 10 and calendar.isleap(x["Year"])) else x["D
     ...: ays"], axis=1)

In [103]: df
Out[103]:
   Days  Year  New_Days
0     1  2005         1
1     2  2006         2
2     3  2008         3
3    50  2009        50
4    70  2008        69
```

Comment: Thank you. Very simple and efficient.